# MagicMock @patch not working as I expected

Tags: python

(Python 2.6)

I am missing something in MagicMock patching

Given the following production code:

```
class MyQueue(object):
    def send(self, message):
        pass

class MessageSender(object):
    def send_all(self, messages):
        queue = MyQueue()
        for message in messages:
            queue.send(message)
```

I have the following test:

```
class MessageSenderTest(TestCase):
    @patch('path.to.MyQueue')
    def test_can_send_all_messages(self, queue):
        messages = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
        sender = MessageSender()
        sender.send_all(messages)
        queue.send.assert_has_calls([call(message) for message in messages])
```

Which gives me:

```
AssertionError: Calls not found.
Expected: [call('foo'), call('bar'), call('baz')]
Actual: []
```

I thought that the mock produced by `sender` would allow me to make an assertion.

Comment: Is your module layout exactly as you have it here where `MyQueue` and `MessageSender` are in the same module? And this module can be accessed as `path.to.MyQueue` in an import statement? Maybe try adding a `print` to the actual `send` method and see if it is being called instead of the mock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that you are not using the patched `queue` instance you are receiving in your test method for  anything, because it is instantiated by your `MessageSender` class. This leads to the mocked `MyQueue` being instantiated each time the `send` method is called. In fact, you can modify your assertion a bit and get the following list of calls:

```
expected = [call()] + [call().send(message) for message in messages]
self.assertEquals(queue.mock_calls, expected)
```

In this form, the test passes. However, I think it would be more natural for the `MessageSender` class to receive the `MyQueue` in its constructor method, so that it can be mocked in the test. See this alternative implementation:

```
# file: main.py

class MyQueue(object):

    def send(self, message):
        pass


class MessageSender(object):

    def __init__(self, queue):
        self.queue = queue

    def send_all(self, messages):
        for message in messages:
            self.queue.send(message)
```

Using this, the test reads much more natural:

```
# file: test.py

import unittest

from mock import patch, call

import main


class MessageSenderTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('main.MyQueue')
    def test_can_send_all_messages(self, queue):
        messages = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
        sender = main.MessageSender(queue)  # <-- here is where you do use `queue`
        sender.send_all(messages)
        queue.send.assert_has_calls([call.send(message) for message in messages])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```